# How to find lowest int score in text file and replace it with higher score with new input in C++

Tags: c++

I made a code which allows 10 player and scores inputted by user. After 10 input the program suppose will continue to ask for name and score and compare with what is already in list of 10 to see if the inputted have score higher than the lowest in the file. If the 11th input have higher score than lowest in the text file it will replace it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
//#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int optionInput;
    int dataCount = 0;

    string playerName;
    int playerPoints;

    bool programActive = true;
    while (programActive)
    {
        //user input menu
        cout << "1. Enter a score\n2. Display scores\n3. Exit" << endl;
        cin >> optionInput;

        if (optionInput == 1)
        {
            system("CLS");

            dataCount++;

            string playerNameInput;
            int playerPointsInput;



            cout << "Insert player name:" << endl;
            cin >> playerNameInput;
            cout << "Insert player points:" << endl;
            cin >> playerPointsInput;

            


            if (dataCount == 11)
            {
                dataCount--;
                // PROBLEM HERE
                // HOW TO REPLACE LOWEST SCORE?
            }
            else
            {
                playerName = playerNameInput;
                playerPoints = playerPointsInput;
                ofstream outFile("scores.txt", ios::app);
                outFile << playerName << ": ";
                outFile << playerPoints << endl;
                outFile.close();
            }
            system("CLS");
            
        }
        else if (optionInput == 2)
        {
            ifstream inFile("scores.txt");

            if (inFile.is_open())
            {
                cout << inFile.rdbuf();
            }

            system("pause");
            system("CLS");
        }
        else if (optionInput == 3)
        {
            programActive = false;
        }
    }
}
```

So far I made it get 10 input but could not figure out how to replace with lowest score already in the file.

What I have tried:

Tried looking for every line with playerPoints and try to store every playerPoints to an array to find lowest number but this causes an error and even that I do not know how to replace oth PlayerPoints and PlayerName with the newly inputted one

```
string input;
ifstream inFile("scores.txt");
while(inFile, input){
//do something
}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QBT3.png)

Is there another simple way to find if 11th score added is higher than lowest score already in text file and if it is higher then it replaces it in the text file? I expect to solve it at `if (dataCount == 11)` mark

Comment: Do not post errors as images. What should `while(inFile, input)` test?

Comment: Did you mean `while(inFile >> input)`? Or possibly `while (std::getline(inFile, input)` to read a line at a time?

Comment: Actually im not even sure how to find lowest score to replace. Better just ignore my attempt those are not helpful.

Comment: Do you have to do this in a file? Otherwise do it inside a vector and after all scores are added sort the vector and save the top ten elements.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem i would use a list. Easy to sort and to maintain. The solution would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct PlayerData
{
    std::string name;
    int32_t points;
};

std::list<PlayerData> ReadFile(const char* filePath, char delimeter)
{
    std::list<PlayerData> result;

    ifstream inFile(filePath);
    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        std::string name;
        std::string points;
        while (std::getline(inFile, name, delimeter) && std::getline(inFile, points))
        {
            result.push_back({ name, stoi(points) });
        }
    }

    return result;
}

void WriteFile(const char* filePath, const std::list<PlayerData>& playerData, char delimeter)
{
    std::ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open(filePath, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);

    if (outFile.is_open())
    {
        for (const auto& it : playerData)
        {
            outFile << it.name << delimeter << it.points << '\n';
        }
        outFile.close();
    }
}

bool playerDataSortFunc(const PlayerData& first, const PlayerData& second)
{
    return first.points > second.points;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t maxDataCount = 11;
    constexpr const char* fileName = "scores.txt";
    constexpr char delimeter = ':';

    auto playerDatas = ReadFile(fileName, delimeter);

    int optionInput;

    bool programActive = true;
    while (programActive)
    {
        //user input menu
        cout << "1. Enter a score\n2. Display scores\n3. Exit" << endl;
        cin >> optionInput;

        if (optionInput == 1)
        {
            system("CLS");

            string playerNameInput;
            int playerPointsInput;


            cout << "Insert player name:" << endl;
            cin >> playerNameInput;
            cout << "Insert player points:" << endl;
            cin >> playerPointsInput;


            playerDatas.push_back({ playerNameInput, playerPointsInput });

            if (playerDatas.size() >= maxDataCount)
            {
                playerDatas.sort(playerDataSortFunc);
                playerDatas.resize(maxDataCount);
            }

            WriteFile(fileName, playerDatas, delimeter);

            system("CLS");

        }
        else if (optionInput == 2)
        {
            ifstream inFile("scores.txt");

            if (inFile.is_open())
            {
                cout << inFile.rdbuf();
            }

            system("pause");
            system("CLS");
        }
        else if (optionInput == 3)
        {
            programActive = false;
        }
    }
}
```